# Using Await Async WhenAll with Disposable Objects

Tags: c#, design-patterns, async-await, idisposable

I've hit a problem trying to process multiple Tasks in parallel (or however the runtime feels fit) when using disposable objects. In the following code snippet, each Processor object is immediately disposed BEFORE it has done the required work.

```
async public Task ProcessData(IEnumerable<int> data)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var d in data)
    {
        using (var processor = new Processor(d))
        {
            processor.Completed += (sender, e) => { // Do something else };
            tasks.Add(processor.ProcessAsync());
        }
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Re-writing the code as below results in the each Processor performing its processing and THEN being disposed, but it's not the most efficient way to run multiple Tasks that don't depend on one another.

```
async public Task ProcessData(IEnumerable<int> data)
{
    foreach (var d in data)
    {
        using (var processor = new Processor(d))
        {
            processor.Completed += (sender, e) => { // Do something else };
            await processor.ProcessAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain why the first example is disposing 'early' and give an example of the best code pattern for this situation.

Comment: Why do you need to dispose the processor objects in that scope? Anyway, the processor object gets disposed since you're leaving the using scope for each turn in the loop.

Comment: I guess I'd hoped that the compiler would work some magic under the covers and automatically set up the disposals as a series of continuations.

Comment: The compiler *does* set up the disposals as a series of continuations, but only if there's an `await` within the `using` block. The fundamental problem with your first example is that the compiler has absolutely no way of knowing that the disposal of each `Processor` needs to be tied to the lifetime of any particular task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It helps to think of `await` as pausing the current *method*, even though it doesn't block the *thread*.

In your first example, when you are executing the `foreach` loop, each time you create a `Processor`, start an operation (saving the operation's `Task` in a list), and then dispose the `Processor`. After your `foreach` loop is finished, then you (asynchronously) wait for all the operations to complete.

In your second example, when you are executing the `foreach` loop, each time you create a `Processor`, start an operation, (asynchronously) wait for it to complete, and then dispose the `Processor`.

To fix this, you should write a helper method, as such:

```
private static async Task ProcessData(int data)
{
  using (var processor = new Processor(d))
  {
    processor.Completed += (sender, e) => { /* Do something else */ };
    await processor.ProcessAsync();
  }
}
```

Your helper method defines a higher-level operation, which will take care of disposing its own `Processor` resource at the appropriate time. Then you can start all your work concurrently as such:

```
public async Task ProcessData(IEnumerable<int> data)
{
  ...
  await Task.WhenAll(data.Select(d => ProcessData(d)));
  ...
}
```

Comment: The helper method is the key to this elegant solution. It wraps a more complex async workflow around the simple ProcessAsync.

Comment: Yes, this is *much* cleaner that the approach I was suggesting :)

Answer (score 2):

Although Stephen Cleary's answer is elegant and probably a better bet in this case, I thought it'd be worth drawing attention to something you get as part of the Reactive Extensions (Rx) that can be useful in similar scenarios. It provides a bunch of helpers relating to `IDisposable`, which would enable you to do this:

```
public async Task ProcessData(IEnumerable<int> data)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    using (var disp = new CompositeDisposable())
    {
        foreach (var d in data)
        {
            var processor = new Processor(d);
            disp.Add(processor);
            processor.Completed += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    // Do something else
                };
            tasks.Add(processor.ProcessAsync());
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

To get that [CompositeDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.disposables.compositedisposable%28v=VS.103%29.aspx), you'll need a NuGet reference to `Rx-Main`.

I don't think I'd use that in this case, but then again I think I'd try to avoid getting to a place where I needed code that looks like this. Having both a `Task` to represent the work being done by your `Processor`, and also an event to signal...something?..that it's complete..? Well `Task` can do that for you, so why have both? And events are relative messy - I invariably find that either an Rx `IObservable<T>` or just using `Task` directly is a better solution than relying on events.

Comment: Thanks Ian. Yes, when I sat down with Matthew we discussed moving away from an eventing model. This was just an example of code that hadn't been fully async'd yet.